# Does Wordpress support template resources/custom fields

Tags: customization, custom-field

I'm pretty new to Wordpress development but say I want, based on my theme's page template I want to create a custom variable.

Ultimately the idea is to create a variable that appears as a field on the admin's post page. That variable can be called in my theme.

As a use case I have buttons on a site that I'd like different colors based on different pages. In making or editing a page I'd like to add a hex for the color in a custom field that inputs that code into the final html page.

I haven't found anything similar to this online. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, **custom fields** or **meta fields** are part of WordPress. There are [all information you need](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).